# Adobe Animate when publishing apk. Error creating files. Namespace is invalid in the application descriptor file.

Tags: actionscript, jquery-animate, adobe

I have an issue with this code. Cannot fathom what is wrong
Does someone have a clue?
Adobe Animate when publishing apk.  Error creating files. Namespace is invalid in the application descriptor file.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>

            <application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/26.0">
            <id>NorskRadioUtenAir</id>
            <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
            <versionLabel/>
            <filename>NorskRadioUtenAir</filename>
            <description/>
            <name>NorskRadioUtenAir</name>
            <copyright/>
            <initialWindow>
            <content>NorskRadioUtenAir.swf</content>
            <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
            <transparent>false</transparent>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
            <aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
            <renderMode>cpu</renderMode>
            <autoOrients>false</autoOrients></initialWindow>
            <icon/>
            <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
            <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>

            <android>
            <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>                    <application>
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4323000" />
            <!-- should be android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" -->
            <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
            </application>
            </manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
            </android>
            <extensions>
            <extensionID>com.pozirk.ads.AdMob</extensionID>
            </extensions>
            </application>
```

Comment: Does your ID tag reflect what you have in the publishing settings (app id)? Normally it would look something like a reverse domain name (ie air.com. Norsk.Radio.Uten.Air). I don't think it has to look that way though.. Sorry can't be more helpful.

Comment: I found my own error. The android:value="4323000" was indeed wrong.